# ubuntu 15.04 alongside windows 10 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

I have sony-vaio E-series model SVE14A15FAP. it was windows7 pre installed but I upgraded to windows10. used for some time and I want to use it alongside ubuntu 15.04, but after a successful installation of Ubuntu 15.04, the boot option is not showing up.it boot straight to windows giving me no option.  Please help me

Comment: pls I need help

Answer (score 1):

You could boot with a Ubuntu Live CD, open a Terminal and execute:

```
sudo grub-install HARDDRIVE
sudo update-grub
```

where HARDDRIVE could be `/dev/sda`.